# How to use grep to extract ip adresses and date/time strings from log file?

Tags: grep

I have a log file that looks like this:

```
May 25 05:34:16 server sshd[1203]: Received disconnect from 192.0.2.2 port 39102:11
May 25 05:34:16 server sshd[1203]: Disconnected from 192.0.2.1 port 39102
```

Now i want to extract all of the ip addresses and the date/time strings at the beginning using grep. I already know how to get the ips:

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' /log.txt
```

and the dates/times:

```
grep -o '[A-Z][a-z][a-z] [0-3][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]' /log.txt
```

but i don't know how to get both at the same time in a format like:

```
May 25 05:34:16 192.0.2.1
```

I've read something like:

```
 grep -oE 'match1|match2' /log.txt
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printing two matches in the single line is easier with `awk`, following will print date(by printing `$1,$2,$3` and all the *valid IP address*.

```
gawk  '{match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/,a);split(a[0],b,".")} b[1]<=255&& b[2]<=255 && b[3]<=255 && b[4]<=255 &&length(a[0]){print $1,$2,$3, a[0]}' log_file
May 25 05:34:16 192.0.2.2
May 25 05:34:16 192.0.2.1
```

**Explanation:** First use match function to capture all the strings having format of `digit.digit.digit.digit` and store them into an array called "`a`" , then split the captured array(`a`) by dot(`.`) characters  and check if each is `<=` 255 to ensure the IP address is valid.

*Note that: GNU awk is used here.*

Also note that, *the regex you mentioned will also print invalid IP addresses* (Eg: `333.222.555.666`).

Comment: Is there a way to also sort the lines by ips? So the same ips would be in a "group"?

Comment: How would i go about couting the number occurrences of an ip and list them by most occurred?

Comment: This is a new requirement, Can you please post a new question with the updated requirement ?

Comment: also, please add the provided input and expected output

Answer (score 0):

You could use your 2 patterns in a capturing group and use those in the replacement using sed:

```
sed -i -E 's#^([A-Z][a-z][a-z] [0-3][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]).* ([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}).*$#\1 \2#g' log.txt
```

That will match:

- `^` Start of string
- `([A-Z][a-z][a-z] [0-3][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9])` Your date/time like pattern
- `.*` Match any char 0+ times
- `([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})` Match space followed your ip like pattern
- `.*` Match any char 0+ times
- `$` End of string

Result

```
May 25 05:34:16 192.0.2.2
May 25 05:34:16 192.0.2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

With any awk in any shell on any UNIX box:

```
$ awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $(NF-2)}' file
May 25 05:34:16 192.0.2.2
May 25 05:34:16 192.0.2.1
```